# How to get the list of all existing tags in a XML using php

Tags: php, xml

i have a xml data which looks like this

```
<channel>
<title>-----</title>
<link>------</link>
<description>---</description>
<lastBuildDate>Tue, 27 Sep 2011 16:37:01 +0000</lastBuildDate>
<language>en</language>
<generator>-------</generator>
<item>
    <title>-----</title>
    <link>-------</link>
    <comments>------</comments>
    <pubDate>Tue, 27 Sep 2011 16:37:01 +0000</pubDate>
    <category>-----</category>
</item>
    <item>
    <title>-----</title>
    <link>-------</link>
    <comments>------</comments>
    <pubDate>Tue, 27 Sep 2011 </pubDate>
    <category>-----</category>
</item>
    <item>
    <title>-----</title>
    <link>-------</link>
    <comments>------</comments>
    <pubDate>Wed, 28 Sep 2011 16:37:01 +0000</pubDate>
    <category>-----</category>
</item>
</channel>
```

from this i need to retrieve all the existing XML tags to the user like, channel, title, link, item etc., including their child tags too.. i mean all the existing tags in the XML file
i need help in how to do that using php, i used DOM and simple XML object but i can only get the values in a specific tag if i know the tag name which i need.,

but i actually need to work with many xml files for which i don't know what is the structure and tags of that particular xml, for that i need to get the existing tags names so that i can display them to the user to select what tags he needs...

I need suggestions for doing this using php.,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my stab at it:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadXML( $yourXmlString ); // or:
$doc->load( $yourXmlUrl );

$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc );
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//*' );

$nodeNames = array();
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    $nodeNames[ $node->nodeName ] = $node->nodeName;
}

var_dump( $nodeNames );
```

I wish I could have made the `xpath` expression a little more efficient though, but I can't think of anything. That's why I continuously overwrite the key of `$nodeNames`.

Come to think of it: perhaps I've misunderstood your question and you don't want the unique element names at all, but want literally **all** elements. If so: how do you want them? As strings? Including their full path?

Comment: i need all the tags to come into an array..!! and i don't need unique elements, i just need all elements to be stored in array..!

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response); ///$response is xml data
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score -4):

Here's a simple example of how to use PHP's `SimpleXML` library as found at http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

```
<?php
include 'example.php';

$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

/* Access the <rating> nodes of the first movie.
 * Output the rating scale, too. */
foreach ($movies->movie[0]->rating as $rating) {
    switch((string) $rating['type']) { // Get attributes as element indices
    case 'thumbs':
        echo $rating, ' thumbs up';
        break;
    case 'stars':
        echo $rating, ' stars';
        break;
    }
}
?>
```