# how to get xml all nodes (tags only) from xml file using php?

Tags: php, xml, tags

I have an xml file shown below.From that file I want to return all the tag names using php.How can I do this.

```
my xml file structure is :

<root>
    <sub>
        <section>
            <name>some name</name>
            <image>image.jpg</image>
            <desc>description</desc>
        </section>
    </sub>
    <sub>
        <section>
            <name>some name</name>
            <image>image.jpg</image>
            <desc>description</desc>
        </section>
    </sub>
</root>
```

I want only tag names i.e name,image,desc.These all tags should be return.

I have tried

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmlDoc->load("file.xml");
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('section');
print_r($nodes);
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far

Comment: $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); $xmlDoc->load("file.xml");$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('section');print_r($nodes);

Comment: Hi, here you have the answer of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636815/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-existing-tags-in-a-xml-using-php

Bye!

Comment: Why do you want to fetch the node names (and not their contents)?

Comment: I want the node names to create table in mysql.I am creating these node names as the column names of my table

Comment: This is the solutions for it.  $xml=simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
foreach($xml as $xm){
 $arr = (array)$xm->section;
}
$res = array_keys($arr);
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($res);